# docker-machine inside Symfony Process

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, docker

I have Laravel 5.2 and try to do something like this

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class MachineCreate extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $process = new Process('docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token *** do-test');
        $process->setTimeout(600);
        $process->run();

        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time i do this i have error:

```
Driver "digitalocean" not found. Do you have the plugin binary accessible in your PATH?
```

But if i do same in `php artisan tinker` i have no errors, everething works fine.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by using ProcessBulder

```
$builder->setPrefix('/usr/local/bin/docker-machine');
$process = $builder
    ->setArguments(array(
        'create',
        '--driver', 'digitalocean',
        '--digitalocean-access-token', '***',
        'do-test'))
    ->getProcess();
$process->run();
```

But stiil i dont know what was reason of this issue...